# React Native Navigation - adding headerRight causes title to be pushed away from the left side

Tags: react-native

Consider the following code:

```
'Points of Interest': {
    screen: Views.POI,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: 'Interesting Places',
    }),
},
```

Produces: 
[image]

However, if I were to add a view of any kind, say, a button, to headerRight like:

```
'Points of Interest': {
    screen: Views.POI,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: 'Interesting Places',
        headerRight: <BackButton navigation={navigation} screen={'Points of Interest'} />,
    }),
 },
```

[image]

What am I missing out here?

Answer (score 1):

Like me I will set backButton in headerLeft and title in center

```
'Points of Interest': {
    screen: Views.POI,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: 'Interesting Places',
        headerLeft: <BackButton navigation={navigation} screen={'Points of Interest'} />,
        headerTitleAlign: 'center', // align center in android
    }),
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`headerTitleAlign`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headertitlealign) to set the left value to `headerTitle`

```
'Points of Interest': {
    screen: Views.POI,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: 'Interesting Places',
        headerRight: <BackButton navigation={navigation} screen={'Points of Interest'} />,
        headerTitleAlign: 'left' 
    }),
 },
```

You can make use of `headerRightContainerStyle` to add further stylings to `headerRight`